# CSS Syntax Difference

Tags: css, syntax

What's the difference between this two statements?

`a.class {
color: red;
}`

and

`.class a {
color: red;
}`

I think that with the second example one would go "inside" classes like

`.class .class2 a {
color: orange;
}`

But you couldn't do that with the first example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a.class` will select `a` element having class `.class` and `.class a` will select ALL `a` elements inside an element having class `.class`.

About this `.class .class2 a { color: orange; }`

It will select ALL `a` elements inside an element having class `.class2` which is further nested in an element having class `.class`

Comment: I'd remove the dot as well. That isn't part of the actual class name.

Comment: @Blender actually the `class` word for `class` is confusing so am using `.` to indicate class though I've highlighted

Answer (score 0):

With the first, all <a>'s with a class of class would be styled as per the style.

With the second, all <a>'s within an element with a class of class would be styled as per the style.

Answer (score 0):

`a.class {color: red}` will color any anchor tag with the class `.class` red. It will only affect anchor tags with that specified class because there is no space separating the `a` and `.class` elements.

`.class a { color: red; }` will color any anchor tags within a parent `.class` element red. The space between the elements declares hierarchy this time, requiring the achor tag to be within the `.class` element.